# Subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are half-spaces and cartesian intervals

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

If an open subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a half-space, is it necessarily a cartesian product of intervals?

Viceversa, is there an example of a subset  $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which is product of cartesian intervals but it is not a half-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open set $A=\{(x,y)| x>y\}$ is a half space, and it is not a cartesian product of intervals.

The set $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ is a cartesian product of intervals, but it is not a half space.